# Load mysql result into php variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, load

Hello I have this code:

```
<?php   $servername = "xxx";
    $username = "xxx";
    $password = "xxx";
    $dbname = "xxx";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 




    $sql = "SELECT varible FROM test";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    echo $result;

    ?>
```

All I want is to load a number from mysql table and load it into php variable and work with that variable as number.
Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT varible FROM test";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $res['varible'];
```

if you have a list then you can use:

```
while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     echo $res['varible'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the last line do it like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT varible FROM test";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row=$conn->fetch_array($result);
echo $row;
```

Answer (score 0):

[`MySQLi::query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) returns a [`MySQLi_Result`](http://php.net/MySQLi_Result) object for `SELECT` queries. You should [read the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).

The `MySQLi_Result` object has a variety of method that you can use to get at the rows.

If we use e.g. `MySQLi_Result::fetch_object()` then we can do it like this:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got it all wrong...think about it one second: if the query returns multiple results how can you store it in one variable?..you need or to loop through the results and assign each time a different value or store the results in an array.